# How to change the colour of current category using jquery and css?

Tags: php, jquery

I am developing a category for product. What I want to achieve is simply click on one category and then this current category background would change. It is just simple as a normal category does. However, I am struggle with achieving it. Can anyone help me with this sticky issue?

Below is the code to generate category

```
 while ( $cat = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) ) 
    { 
        $cats[] = $cat; 
    } 

} 


$list_items = array(); 

foreach ( $cats as $cat ) 
{ 


    if ( ( int ) $cat['parent'] !== ( int ) $parent ) 
    { 
        continue; 
    } 

    $current = $cat['categoryID'];
    $list_items[] = '<nav><li class ="heading">'; 

    $list_items[] = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id ='. $cat['categoryID'].' onClick="getPage('. $cat['categoryID'] . ','.$cat['parent'].')">';
    $list_items[] = $cat['name'];
    $list_items[] = '</a></li>'; 
    $list_items[] = '<ul class ="content">'; 
    $list_items[] = category_list( $cat['categoryID'] ); 
    $list_items[] = '</ul>';

    $list_items[] = '</nav>'; 



    $list_items[] = ''; 

} 


$list_items = implode( '', $list_items ); 


if ( '' == trim( $list_items ) ) 
{ 
    return ''; 
} 


return '<div><ul>' . $list_items . '</ul></div>';
```

My current query for this is as below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".content").hide();

jQuery(".heading").click(function()
{
jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500,function(){
$(this).parent().find('li.heading').css('background-color','green');
$(this).find('.heading').css('background-color','red');
});
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="catbottom">
            <?php include("category.php");echo category_list();?>
        </div>
```

Thank you very much.

The process is as below:

In html, I include category.php which is used to generate category.
for each category, when user click on the category list, the corresponding items would be displayed in a div called "container"

Comment: please remove commented lines and provide a jsfiddle with the final markup so its easier to understand what you are trying to do..

Comment: ok, I will do it now.

Comment: Is it? sorry, I am a new to jsfiddle

Comment: Atleast post your rendered HTML markup, this would help greatly.

Comment: is it better to view now?

Answer (score 3):

I think this should accomplish what you need.

```
$(document).on('click', '.heading', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).next("ul.content").slideToggle();
});
```

I gave your CSS a class called "active", also, I based this answer off this HTML (all best guess):

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li class ="heading">
        <a href="#">rando link</a>
    </li>
        <ul class ="content" style="display: none;">
            <li>blah</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And a fiddle to check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/h2ufk/

Comment: @tymeJV, that is very slick!  nice job! Maybe the only thing that is missing from this demo is using each().

Comment: Sorry, I have another question on this. What happen if there are more than one heading?  I try to use your code, it works when there is only on category ? Let's say, I got fruit and meat. When I click on fruit, its colour would change to active colour(eg: red). Then, when clicking on meat, the fruit would not be active, so its color would not be red, and the meat would be active(red).

Comment: Add the line `$(".heading").removeClass("active");` before the toggleClass

Comment: Sorry, by the way, in your method, how to set the default link (Say the first heading) as the active link. So its background colour is red, then when clicking others, its colour would still change to unactivated colour.